# ASP.NET deploying to server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I’m new to this asp.net web developing. I want to upload my site to server for testing. What are the free server which let you to upload your asp.net web sites for testing using visual studio 2013 or github? And I want to know can I use azure free for testing sites without expiring?  Not for commercial purpose.

Comment: Please have a look at what questions are [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Answer (score 0):

With Azure App Service, you can have up to 10 free sites.  They will not "expire" but you're limited to a total of 165MB outbound network traffic.  Take a look a the App Service Plans page for complete details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/